# Surface of earth seen is 1/4

Tags: trigonometry

At what height from the ground can one see exactly 1/4 th of the Earth's surface ? 
Take earth to be sphere of radius r.

Comment: @nbubis. The question comes from NASA.

Comment: Actually for me, this question came in an Indian Scholarship Examination named KVPY.

Comment: I didn't even know how to proceed with the question :( so haven't tried anything

Comment: @Adeetya. I was just joking !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Earth's radius be $R$, and the height above it be $r$. Moreover, denote the radius of the spherical cap visible as $a$.

Form the right triangle with side $R$ and hypotenuse $R+r$, whose second side has length $\sqrt{(R+r)^2-R^2}$. By triangle similarity you have:

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-R^2}}=\frac{R}{R+r}$$
Solve for $a$ and use the fact that the area of a [spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) is:
$$A=\pi(a^2+(R-\sqrt{R^2-a^2})^2)=\pi (a^2+(R-\sqrt{R^2-a^2})^2)$$

And find for what $r$, $A= \pi R^2$ as requested.

Comment: Thank You, Sir
Answer is coming as R =r which is correct.. !

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{1 \over 4}\,\pars{4\pi r^{2}} = 2\pi r^{2}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta =
4\pi r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2}\quad\imp\quad
\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2} = {1 \over 4}
$$

> $$
> \cos\pars{\alpha} = 1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2} = \half ={r \over r + h}\quad\imp\quad \color{#00f}{\large h = r}
> $$

Comment: Answer is h= r .

Comment: @Adeetya Yes. You are right. I wrote $\pi r^{2}$ as the sphere surface instead of the correct value $4\pi r^{2}$. I already rewrote the answer. Thanks a lot.